# Magento 2 Custom Admin Sub Menu Redirects to White Blank Page!

Tags: module, controllers, 404-page, action

I created a Module and I am getting this 404 page error after I hit the submenu link.
[image]

Here is the code. I can not figure out what is wrong.

acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="UpperLimits_QuantityToShip::parent" title="QuantityToShip" translate="title" sortOrder="30">
                    <resource id="UpperLimits_QuantityToShip::child" title="Child" translate="title" sortOrder="10">
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

routes.xml --- in app/code/UpperLimits/QuantityToShip/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="productlisting" frontName="productlisting">
            <module name="UpperLimits_QuantityToShip"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

menu.xml -- app/code/UpperLimits/QuantityToShip/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="UpperLimits_QuantityToShip::catalog_productlisting" title="Product Listing" module="UpperLimits_QuantityToShip" sortOrder="200" parent="Magento_Catalog::inventory" action="productlisting/product/index" resource="UpperLimits_QuantityToShip::product"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

index php in --- app/code/UpperLimits/QuantityToShip/Controller/adminhtml/Product/index.php

```
<?php

namespace UpperLimits\QuantityToShip\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class Index extends Action
{
  protected $_publicActions = ['index'];
  private $pageFactory;
  public function __construct(
    PageFactory $pageFactory,
    Action\Context $context)
  {
    $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
  }
  public function execute()
  {
    return $this->pageFactory->create();
  }

      /**
     * IsAllowed go to this page
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('UpperLimits_QuantityToShip::parent');
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong.

UPDATE:  NOW I AM JUST GETTING A BANK WHITE PAGE, when I hit submenu link.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change directory name to camel case here `app/code/UpperLimits/QuantityToShip/Controller/adminhtml/Product/index.php` to `app/code/UpperLimits/QuantityToShip/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/index.php` .

**adminhtml** => **Adminhtml**.

When `$this->pageFactory->create();` is executed from controller file it will look for a layout file. Add the layout file at `view/adminhtml/layout/productlisting_product_index.xml` with content similar to given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="page.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Greetings</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="UpperLimits_QuantityToShip::helloworld.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create template file at `view/adminhtml/templates/helloworld.phtml` with some test content like

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Clear cache and it should work. If you are still facing issue please share complete controller code.

Comment: Actully, it did do something.  I had to change the namespace path in my controller index.php file.  `namespace UpperLimits\QuantityToShip\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;`.

However, I am now getting this error and I dont know why.
`
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid return type

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid return type
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#0000000078cc6a5d0000000036339049#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>`

Comment: I also updated the code files up top to show more.

Comment: Ok I believe pagefactory was being called wrong in the use Namespace.  I changed it to `use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;` But now I am just getting a blank white page.

Comment: Have you added layout and template file? Also enable developer mode and un-comment `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in app/bootstrap.php file to see error on the screen.

Comment: That is all set in those files and I added your layout and template files.  This is so hard to debug because I am not getting an error message just a blank white page.

Comment: Can you upload the complete module somewhere in zipped folder and share the link?

Comment: Thank you for the Help.  I started building something else with the site but I need to come back to this eventually.  Here is a google drive link to the module folders.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kxY3t7yt2K5x1WdGr_3POke6ELxH6oVD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have tested it. Make 2 changes in your module and it will work. 1) Change folder name **adminhtml** to **Adminhtml** inside Controller folder. 2) change template file name **HelloWorld.phtml** to **helloworld.phtml** (same name which is mentioned in layout file)

Comment: Thank you so much. You are awesome. I appreciate the help! Now I have to continue building what I am trying to do.  May I come to you for more help if I need it in the future?

Comment: Hi may I ask one more question.  In my module. I created a custom Quantity To Ship Column in Catalog Products Grid following a tutorial.  However, it only showed me how to get manage_stock data.  Do you know how I could get the Qty To Ship data in that custom column Field in Catalog Products Grid, then make it Link to the new admin page I created? First I just want to figure out how to get the Qty To Ship data.  Just thought I'd ask, thank you for your help and time!  Here is the most update module linked below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gg8DUOr0xjDz1V8fNCwgUBSHuPVScEYH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I haven't understood your question properly. Maybe you can create a question for it with proper details of what you want to achieve and what code you have written?